# Typo3 getting image path with CONTENT

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x, typo3-6.2.x

Im setting up a new site on typo3 with a bootstrap carousel in the header. This carousel is on top of every page of the site, so I created a partial for that. The Problem is I want the pictures of the carousel to be exchangeable through the backend. So I created an image-element on a hidden site and tried to get the pictures with typoscript. So far it looks like this:

```
lib.slider=CONTENT
lib.slider {
    table=tt_content


    wrap=<div class="item"><img src="|" /></div>

    select {
        pidInList=12
        where=uid=10

    }


}
```

I get the pictures this way and they are shown in the slider but only in a formatted way with alls this `<csc-textpic>`-crap around it. Is there a way to get just the image path so that it just needs to be wrapped by `<img src""/>`? Or if there is a more elegant way to insert the carousel I'm also open to new suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a content element on a hidden page you can use the "Resources" tab of a page, where you can upload files (in your case images). Usually you use the page on the **top level** of your TYPO3 pagetree for this, so you can **inherit selected images** to all subpages.

[image: TYPO3 Page Resources]

After you have uploaded/selected your images to the page, you can use the following TypoScript to render your image slider.

```
lib.slider = FILES
lib.slider {
  references {
    data = levelmedia:-1, slide
  }
  renderObj = IMAGE
  renderObj {
    file.import.data = file:current:uid
    file.treatIdAsReference = 1
    altText.data = file:current:title
    wrap = <div class="slide">|</div>
  }
  stdWrap.wrap = <div class="slider">|</div>
}
```

In the example above I use `levelmedia:-1, slide` to inherit the selected images from the current page to all subpages. Remove all wraps in the example above if you just want to output  `img` tags in the frontend.

Comment: This works very good so far, thanks. Is there a way to specify the page id, so that typoscript loads the images only from one page? as far as i see it, now it loads the ressources from the page im on first (if im on a subpage, it loads the pictures stored there). And since im not very good at typoscript, is there a way to count the pictures for the carousels navigation?

Comment: Yes, you can specify load images from one page by using 
`references {
  table = pages
  uid.data = YOUR-PAGE-UID
  fieldName = media
}`
I don't know if it is possible to count the amount of images in TS, but if you use a JS carousel, then I would suggest you use JavaScript to count the amount of images.

Comment: How we can display an image randomly?

Comment: @raj Please create a new question.

Comment: @derhansen I found the answer, we need to add listNum = rand in the references option to display the image randomly.
i.e)  references {
    data = levelmedia:-1, slide
    listNum = rand
  }